# How to get the last element of the strings in a column in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe column as follows:

```
name_col
"Anna"
"c(\"Anna\", \n\"Billy\", \n\"Fanny\")"
"c(\"Tom\", \"Tim\"\n)"
"Minnie"
```

I would like to get the last string for each row in the above column,
something like this:

```
 name_col
 "Anna"
 "Fanny"
 "Tim"
 "Minnie"
```

The dput(head(name_col, 4)) looks like this:

```
c("Anna","c(\"Anna\", \"Billy\", \"Fanny\")" ,"c(\"Tom\", \"Tim\")","Minnie")
```

Please let me know if this can be done on dataframe column in R. Thanks

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(head(name_col, 4))` at the end of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data frame `d` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use this substitution:

```
transform(d, name_col = sub('.*"(.*)".*', "\\1", name_col))
```

giving:

```
  name_col
1     Anna
2    Fanny
3      Tim
4   Minnie
```

### Note

The input data frame shown reproducibly:

```
d <- data.frame(name_col = 
  c("Anna",
  "c(\"Anna\", \n\"Billy\", \n\"Fanny\")",
  "c(\"Tom\", \"Tim\"\n)",
  "Minnie"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```